# SWT on different systems

Tags: java, maven, swt

I used Java and SWT's `Browser`. I prepare two system versions of application, first for OSX second for Windows.

Both systems are 64bit

SWT need different libraries for different systems so in Maven I declared both

```
<profile>
    <id>windows-deploy</id>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>osx-deploy</id>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

In the browser I load page and click button (which creates new window) but I do not want open new window, only reload actual browser which new page, I did it like in code below

```
browser.addOpenWindowListener(new OpenWindowListener() {
    public void open(WindowEvent event) {
        Log.debug(TAG + "<>", "Open new page!");
        event.browser = browser;
    }
 });
```

And on OS X system it works great.

But when I try on Windows, after click on button old page do not change. I checked Logs and the message "Open new page!" was written but nothing happens (new page do not load like in OS X). I though that can be something about refreshing after load page by WebKit and `browser.refresh()` refresh browser but there is old content (not new like in OS X).

I debug and checked what happens after `event.browser = browser;` the WebKit from SWT library take control.

What I should do to get the same effect on Windows like on OS X ?

Comment: Please don't overuse the backticks "`" for keywords, they're meant to be used for inline code.

Comment: Ok sorry, I promise I will not use it in wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

Problem is in libraries. On OSX system when we change `event.browser` object, is automatically detected and it working, but on Windows system we need to add to browser `VisibilityWindowListener` as in code fragment below and working fine :)

```
browser.addVisibilityWindowListener(new VisibilityWindowListener() {
            public void hide(WindowEvent event) {
            }

            public void show(WindowEvent event) {
                Browser browser = (Browser) event.widget;
                Shell shell = browser.getShell();

                if (event.location != null)
                    shell.setLocation(event.location);

                if (event.size != null) {
                    Point size = event.size;
                    shell.setSize(shell.computeSize(size.x, size.y));
                }

                shell.open();
            }
        });
```